# Value of 'Content' property in directory properties - how to separate count of subfolders and files?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, files, 19.10

In Ubuntu Files (default file manager) 'Contents' property displays sum of subfolders + files, while I'm used to separate this values. How can I configure it ? Any workarounds are welcome as well.
[image: Ubuntu default file manager]

[image: MEGA cloud storage]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Graham Ubuntu 19.10